# Rails add a model to another model twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've recently run into a few scenarios where I need to add a model to another model more than once.

Examples:

Say a user has a post. But that post should also be able to be shared with other users so it can be viewed/edited by those users. So the post should belong to a user, but also should have an array of users that can also edit it.

Or say a survey should have many questions, but also should have some questions that are separate screening questions. So a survey should have many questions, but also could have many screening questions.

How would I go about adding a second db field that points to the same model as a different field? Right now post would have `user_id:integer` and each question would have a `survey_id:integer`.

For the survey with questions, I think I could probably just add a "screening" boolean property to questions and then just add all questions to the survey.questions array and filter by the screening property. But I'm not sure that's the best route to go.

I'm not sure how I could handle the shared post with the users model though since a user `has_many` posts, but each post could be shared with multiple other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like you need a `has_many, :through` relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

You offload the `user_id` to a different table (defined by a custom model, say, `PostRelation`) where the columns look like:
`user_id | post_id | kind | created_at | updated_at`

You define the kind of relation on the `kind` column (like 'view', 'edit', 'owner'), and `post_id` and `user_id` are self-explanatory.

In this case, the relationships would be:

- Post `has_many :users, through: :post_relation`
- Post `has_many :post_relations`
- User `has_many :posts, through: :post_relation`
- User `has_many :post_relations`
- PostRelation `belongs_to :user`
- PostRelation `belongs_to :post`

Then within the user/posts model you can define custom methods that filter the posts based on the `PostRelation` status:

`class Post
  def editors
    self.post_relations.includes(:users).where(kind: 'edit')
  end
end`